# Quantidade de elementos em vetor ndarray

Tags: python, matriz, numpy

Tenho a seguinte função para contar quantos "jogador" aparecem no vetor `estado[i]`, que é uma linha de uma matriz:

```
for i in range (0, len(estado)):
    if (estado[i].count(jogador) == len(estado)):
        return True
```

Porém "estado" é do tipo `ndarray`, como poderia contar a quantidade de ocorrências de "jogador" em `estado[i]` sendo ela uma `ndarray`?

Answer (score -1):

Vejo a forma mais simples de se filtrar um `ndarray` utilizando o método [`where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). A partir daí, uma tupla é retornada contendo um array com os itens encontrados no primeiro índice, basta verificar a propriedade [`shape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html) do mesmo:

```
for i in range (0, len(estado)):
    # supondo que estado[i] tenha apenas uma dimensão e cada item corresponda a um jogador 
    # e acessando o primeiro item da tupla de retorno das chamadas a "where" e "shape"
    if (np.where(estado[i] == jogador)[0].shape[0] == len(estado)):
        return True
```

E como exemplo:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([['jogador 1', 'jogador 2'], ['jogador 2', 'jogador 3']])

for i in range(0, len(x)):
  print(np.where(x[i] == 'jogador 1')[0].shape[0])
```

O resultado do exemplo seria:

```
1
0
```